# PromQL difference between queries

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I'm new to using Prometheus and I'm trying to understand a couple of things.

I have a java web app that exposes a counter called let's say "my_counter".

What is the difference between the following queries?

```
sum(increase(my_counter[1m]))

sum(increase(my_counter[3m]))
```

If I run these queries in the same time interval of 1 hour why do the two return different results?

What I am trying to achieve is to see how much the counter increased in a configurable time period.

Thanks.

P.S. I'm actually using Grafana to run the queries and select the time range.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that "*the same time interval of 1 hour*" means that while running the presented queries, the exactly same hour has been selected from the time range control panel.

The difference between your queries is that they look at different ranges of time. While the first one examines how much *my_counter* has increased during the last 1-minute-period, the second one examines how much *my_counter* has increased during the last 3-minute-period.

An example with time and counter values:

```
01:20:00 => my_counter: 0
01:21:00 => my_counter: 1
01:22:00 => my_counter: 2
01:23:00 => my_counter: 2
01:23:45 => my_counter: 4 (This is the moment of my_counter examination. Notice the time.)
```

- At 01:23:45, the first query will look at the 1-minute time range between 01:22:45 and 01:23:45, and will show the increase of about 2.
- At the same time, the second query will look at the 3-minute period from 01:20:45 to 01:23:45 and will show the increase of about 4 (because three minutes ago at 01:20:45 *my_counter*'s value was still 0).

The same thing happens in every data point you see in Grafana. The increase query is extrapolated to cover the full time range which means that you may also see non-ingeter values. Here you can find [the actual documentation about the increase query function](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase).

Comment: Hi and thank you for explaining a bit. I think I understood what you did explain but there is still something unclear. The sum function should add all 1m respectively 3m intervals. This means that for 1m I would have 60 intervals with smaller values while 3m will provide me with 20 intervals with greater values. Still, the sum of all of those should still be the same. In your provided example the sum should return 4 in both cases. Right?